# OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error (python)

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to run a script that opens the tor browser via tbselenium on a Linux machine (Raspberry pi 4) using Python.

Here is the script I'm running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tbselenium.tbdriver import TorBrowserDriver

url = "https://monkey.org/"

with TorBrowserDriver("/home/pi/tor-browser_en-US") as driver:
    
    driver.get(url)
```

And here is the error I get when I run the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    with TorBrowserDriver("/home/pi/tor-browser_en-US") as driver:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tbselenium/tbdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    options=options)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1047, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

If anyone could please help me.

Comment: "Exec format error" refers to the executable you are trying to start.  Have you tried it alone, without python?  You would get that message if you tried to use a 32bit on a 64bit system, wrong OS binary, a script missing a `#!` line, ...  Note that Tor is actually firefox, started with specific options, via scripts.  You could check your browser with `file firefox.real` in your Tor browser installation directory.  It will tell you which version you have (binary type, 32 or 64 bits, ...).